# DRF - render SerializerMethodField in serializers.Serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a little problem with getting value from `SerializerMethodField` when using `serializers.Serializer`

*views.py*:

```
class StaticDataView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.StaticDataSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

*serializer.py*

```
class AnimatorStaticDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    data = DataSerializer(data=Data.objects.all(), many=True)
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_user(self, obj):
        return UserSerializer(self.context['request'].user).data
```

When I call to my API view, at the response I get only data key, user isn't rendered. I found that could be because `SerializerMethodField` is `read_only=True` and for this reason `get_initial()` from `rest_framework/serializers.py` doesn't render it. But how can I write it differently when I need to pass context with the user as an instance to UserSerializer. DataSerializer is also using request from context.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: get `user = serializers.SerializerMethodField` in response or pass to nested serializer `self.context['request'].user` as instance